# Stacked column chart height of column not as per gross total with negative values

Tags: google-visualization

I have stacked column chart in which 3 legend values i combined to create stacked chart.
I have issue with height of column not as per gross total with negative values.
[image]

In above example last column height should not above 3000 line as gross total of each will be `- 471 + 740 + 2631 = 2900`.

Here height is positive total (Total Expenses + Mortgage Repayment) shows above 3000 line and negative total (Banked Profit) shows below negative 1500 line. Here 1k, 2k and 3k line is based on all positive records total and -1.5k line based on all negative total.

How can i achieve total height should not beyond total of each values?

Answer (score 1):

While it may seem counter-intuitive, it is perfectly logical in terms of relative proportions.

A quick glance at the docs has not brought up any sort of vertical offset, therefore you might have to preprocess the data and subtract negative values from positive ones. We can try a proportional approach:

The positive values amount to a total of:

```
740 + 2631 = 3371
```

which we convert to a percentage factor:

```
100/3371 = 0.0296...
```

that we apply to individual positive values (I'm rounding values for the readability of this example):

```
 740 * 0.0296... = 21.95%
2631 * 0.0296... = 78.05%
```

Then we turn those percentages into multiplication factors by dividing them by 100, apply them to the total negative value and subtract every instance from their respective positive value:

```
740 + (0.2195 * -471)
740 - 103 = 637

2631 + (0.7805 * -471)
2631 - 368 = 2263
```

Let's make a quick check:

```
2263 + 637 = 2900
```

This is indeed the expected positive value.

The data went from `[-471, 740, 2631]` to `[-471, 637, 2263]`

This should be fairly trivial to implement programmatically. Although this makes the height of individual positive bars technically wrong, it makes the total height accurate.